# How to fix error "cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined" using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to fix the error "cannot invoke an object which can possibly be undefined" using react and typescript.

what i am trying to do?
I am using usecontext react hook and creating a variable from it (dialogContext) in the components (home, Dialog and books component). In doing so i get the above mentioned error.

I am defining DialogContext in helper file like below

```
interface ContextProps {
    setDialogOpen?: (open: boolean) => void;   
}

export const DialogContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({});
```

And importing DialogContext in components where needed that is (Main, home, Dialog components)

```
function MainComponent() {
  let [showDialog, setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);
  return (
      <DialogContext.Provider
          value={{
              setDialogOpen: (open: boolean) => {
                  if (open) {
                      const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('dialog');
                      if (sessionDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
                          setShowDialog(open);
                          sessionStorage.setItem('dialog', 'closed');
                      }
                  } else {
                      setShowDialog(open);
                  }
              },
          }}
      >
      {showDialog && <Dialog DialogContext={DialogContext}/>
          <Route 
              path="/items">
              <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route
              path="/id/item_id">
              <Books/>
          </Route>
      </DialogContext.Provider>
  )     
}


function Home() {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); //get error here
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    )
}


function Books({DialogContext} : Props) {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); //get error here
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
    )    
}

function Dialog() {
    return(
        <div>
            //sometext
           <button onClick={dialogContext.setDialogOpen(false)}> hide</button> //get errror here
        </div>
   )
```

}

What i have tried?

I have added a check for undefined where dialogContext is used in components (Books, Home, Dialog) like for example in Books components i used like below,

```
function Books({DialogContext} : Props) {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        if (dialogContext !== 'undefined') {
            dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); //get error here
        }
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
    )    
}
```

But still the error "cannot invoke an object which can possibly be undefined" throws.

Could someone help me fix this error. thanks.

Edit:

I have tried to do below and it removes the error

```
function Books({DialogContext} : Props) {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        if (dialogContext && dialogContext.setDialogOpen) {
            dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); 
        }
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
    )    
}
```

But instead of adding a check like this in every component what change should i make in the DialogContext helper file or what needs to be changed to fix keep checking for undefined or not. thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `dialogContext?.setDialogOpen` work?

Comment: meaning to use dialogContext ? dialogContext.setDialogOpen : null; ??? hm it is not working.

Comment: i have updated my question the way DialogContext is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of typing mistakes in your code , I've edited the answer based on your comments and here is the final result. you can also see how it's work in codesandbox just [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-dew-7zml2?file=/src/App.tsx:107-1782) to see.

and here is All of your code + a some fixes + a little change in structure

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

interface ContextProps {
  setShowDialog: (open: boolean) => void;
}

const DialogContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
  setShowDialog: (open: boolean) => {}
});

function Home() {
  const dialogContext = React.useContext(DialogContext);
  const handleClick = () => {
    dialogContext.setShowDialog(true); //It's Ok
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>;
}

function Books() {
  const dialogContext = React.useContext(DialogContext);
  const handleClick = () => {
    dialogContext.setShowDialog(true); //get error here
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>;
}

function Dialog() {
  const dialogContext = React.useContext(DialogContext);
  const handleClick = () => {
    dialogContext.setShowDialog(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}> hide</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function MainComponent() {
  const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider
      value={{
        setShowDialog
      }}
    >
      {showDialog && <Dialog />}
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/books">
            <Books />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: After removing ? character for the setDialogOpen meaning removing it from being optional then gives me an error "argument of type  {} is not assignable to  parameter of type 'ContextProps'. Property setDialogOpen is missing in type {} but required in ContextProps.

Comment: i get this in this line export const DialogContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({}); and also this error in the question still exists

Comment: seems like i have to pass some default value in this line export const DialogContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({}); not sure what that could be

Comment: I've edited the code , you can play around with it here on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-dew-7zml2?file=/src/App.tsx:107-1782

Answer (score 1):

There's no sense in providing a default value for the context. It's redundant boilerplate, especially when it's complex.

Just fake the type:

```
const DialogContext = createContext(null as any as ContextProps);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are saying `setDialogOpen` is optional in ContextProps when you provide the `?`. This error will go away if you always require setDialogOpen (remove the `?` from your interface definition)

```
interface ContextProps {
    setDialogOpen: (open: boolean) => void;   
}
```

Alternatively you can call setDialogOpen conditionally

```
setDialogOpen?.(true)
```